# Load testing 1000 users via blazemeter and jmeter but getting 1 user reflection in backend

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, blazemeter

[Let's say I am filling this form and recording it via blazemeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXcHS.png)
[and this is how its looking in jmeter for testing 1000 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoZ0h.jpg)
[this is my backend and it's only reflecting one user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzjzd.jpg)

[I am expecting 1000 differnt users here after load test on jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhU36.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you recorded your test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) it will contain credentials only of the user used during the recording process.

If you want to see 1000 different users - you need to:

1. Have 1000 different names/emails in i.e. [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) and set it up to read the data from the CSV file
3. Replace recorded name and/or email with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the CSV Data Set Config

This way JMeter will read next line on each iteration of each virtual user and will post the data under the authority of a new user.

Comment: already tried that this is the link to the form https://testapp-app.kloudsoft.co/survey/38e288e2-7957-4a05-b024-fb337df2f0f6